# How do I measure the total server resource usage for commands?

Tags: performance

I am using Ubuntu 12.0.4 64 bit server edition and I have to measure the server performance for some specific programs.

Is there a way to record the total System resource usage by a specific command?

For example, I have some 10 commands in a perl script file. Can I measure the total (during total time consumed by the command) CPU run time, %CPU usage, Memory Usage, etc., for each of the 10 commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `time` command (`/usr/bin/time`, not the shell builtin) can report these and a host of other statistics:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f "Real time: %E\nCPU Usage: %P\nAverage Memory Usage: %t" some-command
Real time: 0:01.05
CPU Usage: 99%
Average Memory Usage: 0
```

See the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/time.1.html) for more.